# Unix: binary string using grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep, binary

How can I show at least 3 1's in a binary string using the `grep` command? I tried this `egrep '[1]{3,}'` but that command only shows the consecutive 1's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be missing something... echo "41113" | egrep '[1]{3,}' does return 41113 (with the 111 highlighted in my console).  If you just want the whole line highlighted, echo "41113" | egrep '.*[1]{3,}.*' works.

Comment: Yes but I want a command that also shows the non-consecutive 1's. For example: 1010100000000000. With the command I use the shell only covers the consecutive 1's: 00001110000000.

Comment: Please add some sensible examples to your question. Given the input "10101010000000" should result in the expected output and s.o..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for nonconsecutive 1's, you need to intersperse the pattern with something like `.*`, as well as putting parentheses around the combination, e.g.,

```
grep -E '(1.*){3,}' foo
```